# Как переиспользовать результаты запроса в SQLAlchemy CORE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

Есть сложный запрос возвращающий датасет `fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4, fld5` с ожидаемым числом записей от 20 до 200, к которому потом обращаются неоднократно, в разных разрезах:

```
SELECT DISTINCT fld2, fld3 FROM dataset
```

или

```
SELECT fld1, sum(exttable.fld6) FROM dataset LEFT JOIN exttable GROUP BY fld1
```

На SQL (SQLite) это легко решается временной таблицей, позволяющей переиспользовать данные, без их повторного извлечения из всех таблиц

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dataset AS
SELECT fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4, fld5 FROM ...
```

Есть ли красивое решение на SQLAlchemy CORE?
Например сначала получаем

```
query = select([fld1, fld2, fld3, fld4, fld5]).select_from(complex_join).where(complex_clause)
dataset = query.fetchall()
```

а затем ... ? Вариант с

```
temp_table = table('temp_table', column('fld1'), ..., column('fld5'))
temp_table.create(engine)
temp_table.insert().from_select(select_statement)
... work with temp_table ...
temp_table.drop()
```

не рассматриваю. Не красиво и это не временная таблица, автоматически удаляемая после закрытия соединения, а постоянная, доступная всем из всех коннектов.

PS. Обращаю внимание, работа идет с CORE, а не ORM

Answer (score 1):

После длительного изучения темы понял, что готовых простых решений нет. 
Но если немного реализовать "библиотечный" код, пользовательский будет довольно прост.

Основная особенность данного вопроса, что запрос имеет две ипостаси:

- создание таблицы
- собственно запрос

и соответсвенно к его решению можно подойти с двух сторон.

#### общая часть решений

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
metadata = sa.MetaData()

marker = sa.Table('marker', metadata,
    sa.Column('x1', sa.Integer),
    sa.Column('x2', sa.Integer),
    sa.Column('x3', sa.Integer)
)
metadata.create_all(engine)

conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(marker.insert().values([(1, 2, 3), (1, None, 5)]))
```

#### первично — запрос

Создано на основе фирменного рецепта Алхимии [SelectInto](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/wiki/UsageRecipes/SelectInto)

```
temp_name = "tmp_markers"
# формируем почти обычный запрос, только select_into вместо select
statement = select_into([marker.c.x1, marker.c.x2], temp_name) \
    .where(marker.c.x3 == 5) \
    .where(marker.c.x1.in_([1, 5]))

# выполняем его, попутно получив таблицу в базе 
conn.execute(statement)
# через рефлексию получаем объект созданной таблицы
temp_table = sa.Table(temp_name, metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
```

чтобы это отработало, нужен код, работающий через штатный механизм расширения возможностей Алхимии

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import Select
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

class SelectInto(Select):
    def __init__(self, columns, into, *arg, **kw):
        super(SelectInto, self).__init__(columns, *arg, **kw)
        self.into = into

@compiles(SelectInto, 'sqlite')
def s_into(element, compiler, **kw):
    text = compiler.visit_select(element)
#    return 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE {} AS {}'.format(element.into, text)
    return 'CREATE TABLE {} AS {}'.format(element.into, text)

def select_into(columns, name):
    return SelectInto(columns, name)
```

Основной недостаток — невозможность грамотно указать, какую таблицу, временную (закоментировано) или постоянную, нам надо.
Теоретически, никто не мешает добавить еще один параметр, но создание запроса select, это не место для указания ddl базы.
С одной стороны, многословная реализация возможности, с другой — очень простое применение в пользовательском коде. Рефлексию можно завернуть в функцию/лямбду и получать вообще коротко: `temp_table = table_ref(table_name)`. Выгодно использовать где много одинаковой работы с временными таблицами, но более грамотным считаю:

#### первично — создание

```
temp_name = "tmp_markers"
statement = sa.sql.select([marker.c.x1, marker.c.x2]) \
    .where(marker.c.x3 == 5) \
    .where(marker.c.x1.in_([1, 5]))

# создаем объект таблицы, на основе полей содержащихся в запросе
temp_table = TableOn(temp_name, metadata, statement, prefixes=['TEMPORARY'])
# и саму ее в базе данных
temp_table.create(engine)
# и только потом, наполняем ее данными, штатными средсвами
conn.execute(temp_table.insert().from_select(temp_table.c.keys(), statement))
```

Немного более многословно в пользовательском коде, но явное лучше неявного, плюс управление постоянная/временная в нужном месте.
И решается это крайне простым "библиотечным" кодом

```
class TableOn(sa.Table):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        name, metadata, selectable, *args = args
        query_fields = [c.copy() for c in selectable.c]  # возможно создвать неполную копию sa.Column(c.name, c.type)
        return super().__new__(cls, name, metadata, *query_fields, *args, **kwargs)
```

В целом, это недалеко ушло от варианта предложенного в вопросе, но... это действительно временные таблицы, и создание объекта таблицы автоматизировано. Т.е. можно завернуть в функцию и получать временную таблицу одним простым вызовом.